# Get output data from x264vfw filter

Tags: .net, rtsp, live-streaming, directshow.net, x264

I need get H264 stream from x264 encoder and make some kind of live streaming server. Client will connect to the server, then via rtsp recieve video. How can I get data from x264vfw output pin?
In what way better do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pins connect to pins, you need to connect this pin to another filter. This might be a filter, like Sample Grabber, that make the data available outside the DirectShow pipeline.

Comment: There is one problem when graph end`s with SGrabber it`s crush with com exeption. When I`m using grabber like transform filter and render video all work fine.

Comment: Answer: Sample Grabber is Transfer filter, so output pin must be connect to Null Render for Example. Usefull link about Sample Grabber http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43024/Capture-image-from-a-streaming-URL-using-different